# Can I say $\frac{4}{0}\neq$ something??

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Can I say $\frac{4}{0}\neq$ something? For example,

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},~\frac{4}{x}\neq0$.

In this quantified statement, $x$ could be $0$ at a moment, leading the $\frac{4}{x}$ to be meaningless. So in this case, is a statement/proposition that includes a meaningless term, such as $\frac{4}{0}$ in $\frac{4}{x}\neq0$ a legal(I mean, it is OK to write so) statement?

Comment: No, it's equal to everything. This is why you shouldn't divide by zero

Comment: @Justin It's not equal to any real, since assuming it is equal to a real leads to contradiction.

Comment: But you can say : $\forall x \in \mathbb R \ (4 \ne x 0)$.

Comment: *Valid* means true in all interpretation; thus $∀x \ (x>0 → x^2>0)$ is **not** valid.

Comment: *True* is always true *with respect to* one specific interpretation; thus, in the domain of e.g. *natural numbers* with the usual meaning for >, it is obviously true.

Comment: In a different domain, with e.g. dogs and numbers... it depends on the interpretation of >: what is (according to this would-be interpretation) the meaning of $Fido > Bob$ ? and What does it mean $Fido^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The quantifier doesn't change anything, you're still making an undefined statement.  It's as invalid as it is in any other context.

Comment: So follow by the same logic, the statement $\forall x, (x>0\rightarrow x^2>0)$ is also ill, right? Because $x$ can be anything, maybe a dog, how can we say *"a dog is greater than 0"*?

Comment: @Eric - NO; in the usual approach to first order logic, the predicates and relations are always defined. Thus, if you interpret your formula in a "universe" with dogs **and** numbers, you have to interpret the binary relation $>$ in a way that $x > y$ is always meaningful.

Comment: But why you think that an arithmetical formula is of some use with dogs ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Because I remember the book said if the discourse is not particularly specified, it is the set of everything, including numbers, dogs, etc. In the sentence "$\forall x, (x>0\rightarrow x^2>0)$", the $x$ can be anything, can't it? So there is a moment that the proposition $\text{dog}>0\rightarrow \text{dog}^2>0$ occurs.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  One answer said that $\forall x, (x>0\rightarrow x^2>0)$ is an undefined statement, and one said that it is valid, and also true. May I ask what do you think? :-)